# Python 3.5 - Generate Text Files

Tags: python, loops, file-io

I have to write a program that prompts a user to enter six test names and their scores and writes them to a text file named tests.txt. I must use a loop and each input should be written to its own line in the file. The program should generate a confirmation message when done.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
Entering six tests and scores
Enter test name objects 
Enter % score on this test 88
Enter test name loops 
Enter % score on this test 95
Enter test name selections.   
Enter % score on this test 86 
Enter test name variables
Enter % score on this test 82
Enter test name files
Enter % score on this test 100
Enter test name functions
Enter % score on this test 80
File was created successfully
```

Then I must write another program that uses a loop to read and process the tests.txt from the previous program. The program must output a two-column table showing the test names and scores. When the table is complete, the average should be displayed accurate to one decimal place.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
Reading six tests and scores
TEST          SCORE
objects       88
loops         95
selections    86
variables     82
files         100
functions     80

Average is 88.5
```

This is far and beyond anything I’ve had to do. So far my tasks have been quite simple. I’m using Python 3.5 so I can’t use any new functions.

**EDIT WITH PROGRESS**:

So far I have this for the first program to generate the txt document:

```
def main():
myfile = open('test.txt', 'w')
test = input('Please enter test name or enter to quit ')

while test != '':
    score = int(input('Enter % score on this test '))
    myfile.write(test + '\n')
    myfile.write(str(score) + '\n')
    test = input('Please enter test name or enter to quit ')

myfile.close()
print('File was created successfully')
```

main()

The second program looks like this and is in rough shape:

```
def main():
f = open('test.txt', 'r'); 
text = f.read(); 
f.close()
```

main()

Can someone offer me some direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1

You can write to a file like so:

```
with open('/path/to/your/file.name', 'w') as f:
    f.write('text')
```

which will create the file if it doesn't exist and overwrite all content. If you replace `'w'` with `'a'` it will append to the end of the file (you need to add newlines yourself).

If at the beginning of your program you do `f = open('/path/to/your/file.name', 'w')` and then at the end do `f.close()`, all content in between will be written (that is, it will not overwrite previous `write` operations until the output stream is flushed and closed).

For example:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write('hello, ')
f.write('world!\n')
f.close()
```

will set the content of `file.txt` to `hello, world!`

## Part 2

The average of a list is the sum of its elements divided by the number of elements. Literally just `lambda array: sum(array) / len(array)`...

## Part 3

To read from a file, you can do `f = open('file.txt', 'r'); text = f.read(); f.close()`. `readline` reads a line instead of the whole file.

Writing the actual program itself should be fairly trivial from this point on so I will leave the actual coding to you since this looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: What does ‘f’ typically mean? I’ve never had to use that before.

Comment: @GoldDial `f` is just a variable name... here I use `f` to represent a `file` (or rather, a `_io.TextIOWrapper`)